# Why won't this array initialize?

Tags: c++, arrays

This is essentially what I'm trying to do, but not the actual source code.

`namespace namespace {
        int array [3];
    }
    namespace::array={1,2,3}`

my gcc asks for an expression, and I'm not sure of what to do. Must I  `namespace::array[1];` each individual element?

Answer (score 6):

You can only use an initializer list in a definition:

```
int array[3] = { 1, 2, 3 };
```

If you use:

```
int array[3];
```

then you need to initialize the array in a function, using

```
array[0] = 1; 
array[1] = 2; 
array[2] = 3;
```

Answer (score 3):

Although it an odd mixture of C99 and C++, gcc allows this:

```
#include <string.h>
int a[3];

int main()
{
    memcpy(a, (int[3]){ 1, 2, 3}, sizeof(a));
}
```

!

Comment: ..that is indeed odd, I've never seen anything like that before! +1 for uniqueness...

Comment: I checked the assembly and it does work. I suspect it would also work for non-constant expressions.

Answer (score 0):

How about `namespace ns { int array[3] = {1, 2, 3}; }`?

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways:

1) Explicitly set values for each element:

```
namespace ns {
    int array [3];
}
ns::array[0]=1;
ns::array[1]=2;
ns::array[2]=3;
\\ or if they should contain consequtive values:
\\ for (size_t i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
\\     ns::array[i] = i + 1;
```

2) If you want initialize static array in place of its declaration, then you could move it initializer list as follows:

```
namespace ns {
    int array[3] = {1, 2, 3};
}
```

3) Use `typedef`:

```
namespace ns {
    typedef int array_t[3];
}
ns::array_t array = {1, 2, 3};
```

3) Also you can make some research of std::tr1::array, which may be used as such:

```
std::tr1::array<int, 3> arr = {1, 2, 3};
```